# How to update shopify order created_at date

Tags: shopify

I am wondering if it is possible to manually edit the created_at date for an order.  This would be extremely useful for importing order records into a users shopify store.

Comment: i'm thinking to use this https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/sell-through-the-checkout-api#creating-a-checkout

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the created_at date. It is read-only. As for importing orders into a store? What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing historical data you can set the field `processed_at` and import the order and it will look as though it was placed on that date

Comment: You’re welcome. If it’s working please accept my answer